# Replicate curl request to Jenkins in Java

Tags: java, jenkins, curl, jenkins-api

There are a hundred questions like this but I couldn't find any working answer to my question.

With curl I have a **working** request, response is `201: created`:

```
curl -i -X POST https://username:APITOKEN@jenkins-server/job/jobName/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN -H "Jenkins-Crumb:xxxx"
```

However, if I try to replicate the same request in Java, I get a `403 No valid crumb was included in the request`. CSRF is activated (with proxy compatibility enabled).

My Java implementation (using org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore v.4.4.9):

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
String url = "https://username:" + apiToken + "@" + "jenkins-server/job/jobName/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN";
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.addHeader("Jenkins-Crumb", "xxxx");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT**
I have tried with other Java libraries as well (Unirest, OkHttp) resulting in the same response code `403`. *Tried also with Python (requests library) where it works like a charm:*

```
requests.request("POST", "https://username:ApiToken@jenkins-server/job/jobname/buildWithParameters", data="", headers={"Jenkins-Crumb": "xxx"}, params={"token":"TOKEN"})
```